# Referencing cells in other sheets in the same workbook by client

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

I have a workbook designed to keep track of client invoicing, and I need to know how to reference a cell in different sheets by client. I want the "Amount Owed" by a specific client for one month to be reflected on the next month's worksheet under their respective "Past Balance" column.

The issue is that the positions of the client change every month according to clients we have gained/lost as they are placed alphabetically. This means the reference cell also needs to change accordingly. For example, if Yelnats, Stanley is in column A1, and his "Amount Owed" for May is in B1, I would reference that cell in the June sheet. But, if we take on Picard, Jean Luc, then Stanley becomes A2. I can manually change this each month, but there are far more clients than this and it would take a while.

I need to know how to reference the cell on the previous sheet even when the clients go out of order.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the vlookup function, as explained [here](http://howtovlookupinexcel.com/)?